# Protect workbook but still allow macro to create new worksheets

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an Excel workbook that contains a macro that creates new sheets to be filled in by the user. I want to protect the sheets and workbook so that the user can't change anything by mistake. However, once I protected the workbook, the macro doesn't work anymore because the workbook is protected.

Is there a way to protect the workbook, but still allow the user to run the macro and have it create new sheets?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the protection inside the macro, create your sheets and enable protection still by code.

This requires protection password to be stored in the code, however as I understand your question is less of a concern.

Comment: than you for your answer, it had put to thinking and just used record macro and then filled in the password then dit the copy and then filled in the password. this way now it automatically unprotect and protect the workbook again.